# How do I prevent an input from being saved if certain conditions are not met

Tags: ios, swift

I have created three textfields of title, username, and password.
I want it so if the the title doesn't already exist in the coredata, then it be added, but if it already exists, to show and alert message (which works) but it still gets added to the coredata for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
  @IBAction func savePasswordButton(_ sender: Any) {

        if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {

            let holder = PasswordCoreData(entity: PasswordCoreData.entity(), insertInto: context)

            if let title = createHolderItem.text {
                holder.item = title
                holder.username = createHolderUsername.text!
                holder.password = createHolderPassword.text!
            }

            if homeVC.mainframe.contains(where: { $0.username == holder.username }) {
                let title = "Duplicate"
                let message = "(holder.item) already exists"
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) in alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                }))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else {
                try? context.save()

                navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the creation of `holder` to the `else`.

```
@IBAction func savePasswordButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {
        if homeVC.mainframe.contains(where: { $0.username == createHolderUsername.text! }) {
            let title = "Duplicate"
            let message = "\(createHolderUsername.text!) already exists"
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            let holder = PasswordCoreData(entity: PasswordCoreData.entity(), insertInto: context)

            if let title = createHolderItem.text {
                holder.item = title
                holder.username = createHolderUsername.text!
                holder.password = createHolderPassword.text!
            }

            try? context.save()

            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```